# React strange overflow in mobile

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

[image]

on small screens, that part appears, now, adjust all the divs to 100vw and it continues to appear

Any recommendation?

Comment: without codes, how can we know where the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

Please provide a sample of your code but it looks like it has to do something with your font-size or a phrase is too big that bleeds the device's width